# Bot sometimes posts NaN when I ask for a random image

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, discord

I am currently making a bot using the discord.js module. I am not very good in JavaScript or programming in general, and I've tried asking this everywhere, but I am unable to fix it.

My bot is supposed to pull an image from an array with 12 images saved locally on my computer. Sometimes this works successfully, but sometimes it simply replies IN DISCORD (not in console) with "NaN".

```
 else if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "duckquery")) {
    var ducks = [ {file: "./img/ducks1.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks2.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks3.jpg"}, +
    {file: "./img/ducks4.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks5.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks6.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks7.jpg"}, +
    {file: "./img/ducks8.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks9.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks10.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks11.jpg"}, +
    {file: "./img/ducks12.jpg"}];

    var duck = ducks[Math.floor(Math.random()*(ducks.length))]
    msg.channel.send(duck);
```

Comment: remove your `+` signs in the `ducks` definition.

Comment: It seems to have worked, thank you so much! 
I read somewhere you needed the + signs to continue your code on a new line?

Comment: If you are concatenating a string, you use `+` like `"string 1" + "string 2"`, but not to continue on another row.

Comment: _I've tried asking this everywhere_ - we discourage undeclared cross-posting here. If you have posted this in other fora, please edit or post a follow-up on those question(s) pointing to all other instances, and especially this one. This will help future readers, who will be able to see that you already have an answer, and so they can find they do not need to waste their time posting an answer that you no longer need.

Comment: I had previously asked in irc and discord chats which I am no longer part of, but this is the first forum I ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `+`, since that is trying to add two objects, giving you a `NaN` (Not a Number)

```
var ducks = [ {file: "./img/ducks1.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks2.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks3.jpg"}, +
{file: "./img/ducks4.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks5.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks6.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks7.jpg"}, +
{file: "./img/ducks8.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks9.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks10.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks11.jpg"}, +
{file: "./img/ducks12.jpg"}];
```

Printing out ducks:

```
[Object, Object, Object, NaN, Object, Object, Object, NaN, Object, Object, Object, NaN]
```

Instead use:

```
var ducks = [
    {file: "./img/ducks1.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks2.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks3.jpg"},
    {file: "./img/ducks4.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks5.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks6.jpg"},
    {file: "./img/ducks7.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks8.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks9.jpg"},
    {file: "./img/ducks10.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks11.jpg"}, {file: "./img/ducks12.jpg"}
];
```

That gives you objects:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Are you sure that you need an array of objects instead of an array of strings?

```
var ducks = [
 "./img/ducks1.jpg", "./img/ducks2.jpg", "./img/ducks3.jpg",
 "./img/ducks4.jpg", "./img/ducks5.jpg", "./img/ducks6.jpg",
 "./img/ducks7.jpg", "./img/ducks8.jpg", "./img/ducks9.jpg",
 "./img/ducks10.jpg", "./img/ducks11.jpg", "./img/ducks12.jpg"
];
```

Comment: This makes sense, thank you! Looks much nicer too :)